# How to remove records in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to remove records length equal to two. Is there any direct query to remove those records? Reading raw by raw and delete take huge time. Because my database contain more than 4 million records.

ID Column1

1  abcde bgrft

2  ab

3  bgtyk

4  gh

I want to delete record 2 and 4. Because that size=2.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide examples of data that you want to delete (and don't want to delete).

Comment: @MitchWheat What do you mean? You mean I want to read raw by raw and delete?

Comment: OK, that's a bit better: Search for something like  "TSQL large batch delete"

Comment: BTW 4 million rows isn't that many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that by 'size' you mean string length

```
delete from mytable where length(Column1) = 2
```

Comment: Tree Thanx lot. That works fine for me. Have a nice day :).(Unfortunately I got -3 for my question :( ). Thanx.